# How can I detect when my OptaPlanner solver stops running in my Java Spring application?

Tags: java, spring, optaplanner

I create an application that uses OptaPlanner to solve optimization problems. However I can't get an action to be performed when the solver stops, for the moment my solver stops after 5 seconds but I have no way of knowing it and therefore of exploit the result.

Maybe set up listeners?

Comment: Hello there, please share your code and outcome for further discussion

Answer (score 2):

Are you using SolverManager? If so, you can use one of the SolverManager methods that support a `finalBestSolutionListener`

- https://docs.optaplanner.org/latestFinal/optaplanner-javadoc/org/optaplanner/core/api/solver/SolverManager.html#solve(ProblemId_,Solution_,java.util.function.Consumer)
- https://docs.optaplanner.org/latestFinal/optaplanner-javadoc/org/optaplanner/core/api/solver/SolverManager.html#solveAndListen(ProblemId_,java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.Consumer,java.util.function.Consumer,java.util.function.BiConsumer)

```java
solverManager.solve(1L, MyClass::getProblem, finalBestSolution -> {
    // process final solution here
});

solverManager.solveAndListen(1L,
    MyClass::getProblem
    bestSolution -> {
        // process intermediate solution here
    },
    finalBestSolution -> {
        // process final solution here
    },
    null); // Use null so default exception handler is used
```

or the `getFinalBestSolution()` method of `SolverJob` (which is what `SolverManager.solve` and `SolverManager.solveAndListen` returns):

- https://docs.optaplanner.org/latestFinal/optaplanner-javadoc/org/optaplanner/core/api/solver/SolverJob.html#getFinalBestSolution()

```java
SolverJob<ProblemType, Long> solverJob = solverManager.solve(1L, problem);
ProblemType bestSolution = solverJob.getFinalBestSolution();
```